# Identifying local minima in a histogram

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm interested in finding the local minima in a histogram that roughly resembles

[image]

I'd want to find the local minimum at 109.258, and the easiest way to do so would be to identify whether the number of counts at 109.258 is lower than the average number of counts around in some interval around (and including 109.258). It's identifying this interval that's the most difficult part for me.

As for the source of this data, it's a histogram with 100 bins of non-uniform width. Each bin has a value (shown on the x-axis), and a count of the samples falling into that bin (shown on the y-axis). What I'm trying to do is find the "best" place to split the histogram. Each side of the split is propagated down a binary tree, as part of a classification algorithm.

I'm thinking that my best course of action would be to try to fit a curve to this histogram, using something like the [Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) and then to compare the local minima to find the "best" one. A proper measure of "best" would include some indication of the significance of that split, which is measured as the difference between the average counts in the interval to the left and the average of the counts in the interval to the right, and then maybe weight each difference with the number of counts included to get a composite measurement of "best," if that makes sense.

Either way, computational complexity of the algorithm isn't a huge issue, 100 bins is about the maximum number I'd expect to encounter. However, this calculation will be performed once for each sample, so keeping it linear with respect to the number of bins would, of course, be ideal.

By the way, I'm doing everything in C++, and make use of the boost libraries and STL, so nothing is off-limits in that regard.

Any thoughts or insights concerning best practices would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think local minimum definitions is more simple: if f(i) < f(i-1) and f(i) < f(i+1), i is local minimum.

Comment: Please describe the meaning of the histogram values and the practical purpose of your method at all. Because: finding local minima is easy, as other answers describe. Finding local minima will most probably be the first step of your solution anyway! But selecting the "best" local minimum for splitting is still a vague issue. Describing the actual (practical) problem should help.

Comment: To clarify the problem a little more, I'm looking to find the most appropriate place to split the histogram. This histogram is used as part of a sequential (online) classifier that propagates samples down a classification tree using a test to decide whether the sample belongs in the left or right sub-tree. For each feature in the tree, a histogram is created, which keeps track of the "nature" of the samples without saving the samples. Thus, I'm looking for a way to partition the histogram at the most sensible point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly *kmore* wants to partition two "peaks" based on the largest separation (product of histogram count and bin distance). If this is true:

1. Find all maxs.
2. for each max build rectangles like in Fig.
3. Find rectangle with max **white area**, which gives you the x range to find desirable bin 109.258

[image]

Comment: This is actually a very good solution that's, at a maximum, O(num_bins). I'm still not sure whether this is the best solution, because in the worst case, you're going to have a rectangle every other bin. For extremely jagged data, you'd still need to extrapolate some sort of trend. This is essentially a moving average looking at the previous m bins, where m = window size (number of previous bins to consider). That'd smooth the graph enough to remove all but the largest rectangles, I think.

Comment: @kmore Sometimes I use a simple trick to fight noise (jagged data): build two histograms with different bin size (let say 1:1.3). If your analyses gives you close results for both of them - you are OK. If not - mark data as suspicious and use more sophisticated algorithm (like peak detection from ROOT)

Comment: @kmore Forgot another hint: as soon as you build a rectangle everything **inside** this rectangle become irrelevant, you don't have to build "sub-rectangles". That speeds up you calculation...

Answer (score 6):

Levenberg–Marquardt is not so good a choice in a rugged optimization terrain -- and yours is pretty rugged. There are lots of local minima there. Levenberg–Marquardt might well find the local minimum at about 100. Or it might find one the two global minima at the extremes of the graph where the function tails off to zero.

You want something that finds the most significant local minimum. For example, some kind of clustering algorithm. Here is a very simple one:

Step 1:
Find the local extrema in your data set. These are the extrema at the extremes of the range plus the internal local minima and maxima. With your histogram you should have an odd number of such extrema, alternating between minima and maxima.

Step 2:
Find the pair with the smallest delta. This will either be a (local max, local min) or a (local min, local max) pair.

Step 3:
Find a pair of elements to remove, one of

1. The pair found by step 2
2. The pair comprising the first element of the pair from step 2 and its predecessor
3. The pair comprising the last element of the pair from step 2 and its successor

When the found pair includes a boundary point you should use option 2 or 3, as appropriate. For an internal pair, you might want to use some heuristics in choosing between the three choices. Or you could just do the simple thing and use the found pair.

Step 4:
Delete the pair of elements from step 3, keeping track of the deleted pair.

Step 5:
Repeat steps 2 to 4 until there are only three elements left in the extrema data set (the extremes of the range plus a local max, hopefully the global max).

The last-removed minima is what you want.

There are lots of other clustering algorithms. The one I presented is rather crude and obviously isn't particularly fast. One that extends nicely to a lot more data, and higher dimensional data is the Expectation Maximization algorithm. Simulated annealing (Metropolis-Hastings) could also be adapted to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can, of course be transformed into one of peak finding by functional manipulation of the data (inversion or negation are obvious candidates).

Alternatively, if the example is typical, one might begin with peak-finding in the untransformed data and seek regions where the peaks are (relatively) widely separated as candidates for containing a good local minima.

[I am forever recommending](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=peak%20detection%20user:2509) the method used by the [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) [TSpectrum](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TSpectrum.html) classes for peak finding.

The underling algorithm is discussed in detail in

- M.Morhac et al.: *Background elimination methods for multidimensional coincidence gamma-ray spectra.* Nuclear Instruments and Methods in Physics Research A 401 (1997) 113-132.
- M.Morhac et al.: *Efficient one- and two-dimensional Gold deconvolution and its application to gamma-ray spectra decomposition.* Nuclear Instruments and Methods in Physics Research A 401 (1997) 385-408.
- M.Morhac et al.: *Identification of peaks in multidimensional coincidence gamma-ray spectra.* Nuclear Instruments and Methods in Research Physics A 443(2000), 108-125.

Copies of these papers are maintained on the ROOT web site and linked in the TSpectrum documentation for those that do not have a subscription to NIM A.

Comment: Very nice. OK, OK, you complaining system (5 more to go ...) -- very very nice.

Answer (score 1):

What you want seems to be more complicated than just a local minimum.  Also, the local minimum concept depends strongly on your choice of bins.

Have you heard about [Otsu's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method)?  It might be more along the lines of what you want.

Here's another [Otsu's method link](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/otsuThreshold.html).